# Is it possible to apply to positions that require security clearances as a non-US citizen?

Tags: international, security-clearance

I am looking to apply for positions in the defense industry, in the US. I am a non-US citizen. Is it possible for my prospective company to sponsor me so I can hold a security clearance? Is there any possibility or a course of action to take to be eligible to apply for such positions?

Comment: I am guessing that your current citezenship might affect this, might be a difference if you are from a country regarded as an adversary or a close ally.

Comment: Do you have experience within defence? What sort of role are you looking for (e.g. software, old school engineering, business tasks (e.g. finance or HR), sales, project management),  Are you looking at applying for for a role within the US, or locally in your home country? Also worth noting defence contractors have roles where no clearance is required, but your nationality could impact this.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I am currently employed in the defense industry. I am an R&D engineer, looking for a similar role. I am looking for roles in the US, some say that being able to obtain a clearance is required but I am unsure if a sponsorship makes it possible for me to obtain one.

Comment: Jobs within the US Defense industry are one of the few jobs where   a company is legally allowed to disqualify an applicant due their nationality. In other words, depending on the job, an applicant from Iran can be disqualified while an applicant from Canada could be allowed. It’s entirely dependent on the project and the classification of the data. In the case of SpaceX, they are legally not allowed, to hire anyone except a national born citizen due to rockets being classified as a weapon. Ultimately it’s up to the applicant to be eligible for the clearance.

Comment: If anything, previously having worked in defence for a foreign country may work against you, if you give them reason to suspect that you might be working on their behalf to spy on the American defence industry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's been over 40 years since I've had to deal with security clearances and I'm certain that things have changed, so a quick internet search found:

> Non-U.S. citizens do not qualify for a security clearance. However, if
> a non-U.S. citizen requires access to U.S. classified information and
> meets the requirements of the 32 Code of Federal Regulations (CFR)
> 117.10(k), a Limited Access Authorization (LAA) no higher than the Secret level may be issued.

The requirements for an LAA include:

1. The compelling reason for not employing a cleared or clearable U.S. citizen.
2. A statement of the unusual expertise possessed by the applicant.

There are many more additional requirements that can be found [online](https://www.dcsa.mil/mc/ctp/int/security/).

In general, receiving a security clearance is a difficult and arduous process even for US citizens. Unless you have significant expertise that directly applies to the position it is unlikely that you would qualify for an LAA.

It also generally takes some time to complete the process, often months or longer. So a potential employer might be hesitant to consider you for a position even if they feel you meet the requirements for an LAA.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I have easily transferrable, practical experience, and I will be applying to a position that is basically looking for me in almost all aspects. So if this was a regular application I could get the job easily. I am curious if companies go through the trouble of sponsoring someone, even if I match the job description pretty well.

Comment: @GuarneerFPS,  Security clearance isn't like an H-1B where having the right skills can get you approved.  The employer might be more likely to take a chance on you, but it won't make you more likely to get approved for the clearance.

Comment: @GuarneerFPS, My son went through the security clearance process for a job in the nuclear weapons industry.  The investigator talked to his mom & me about the process while interviewing us (because I'm ex-Navy with former Top Secret+ clearance).  Any significant time abroad in a problematic country even for a citizen can be disqualifying.  And they need to talk to everyone in your life and history.  Beyond the obvious disqualifiers, growing up in a foreign country would likely render the process difficult to complete.

Comment: @TigerGuy thank you for the insightful comment. I understand my chances are low, to say the least. I might just give it a shot in the end, but considering all the comments, I don't think this will work out.

Comment: It most certainly is a waste of your time but since the application process is only a few minutes of your time you have nothing to lose. Now if by some miracle you are selected you will have to determine if will ultimately receive that clearance, being beyond truthful, is the only way for the security manager to make any sort of determination on that front.  The companies security manager will be the first person you will want to talk to, if they do their job, they won’t submit your background check unless it will ultimately get approved

Comment: I'll second @Donald's opinion.  I strongly suspect the exception is intended for an "inventor/discoverer of something new and unique that the DoD wants to take black" not an ordinary "perfect fit for the job description"; and is intended solely for cases where there is no other possible person who could do the job.

Comment: Are there non-national born individuals that have high security clearances, I am sure they exist, but still are unable to see any information that isn’t releasable to their country of origin. Seems my SpaceX example can be used twice. Defense industry suggests ties to the US military, which means information would be tied to national security, and most information like that wouldn’t be releasable unless the country of origin is a US partner.